# Fields not showing on publish/edit page

Tags: publish-layout, field-editor

I have a site we are setting up on EE 2.72, and without realizing there was a known issue it i started using the Field Editor add-on to add fields.  It was throwing some errors here and there but seemed to save things ok.

The issue I'm having is that now I'm getting some fields that just won't show on the publish page layout.  I the edit layout sidebar they show as empty squares.  When you click on the squares it switches to the eyeball but doesn't actually show in the layout.

[image]

I tried removing the field and adding it without field editor, removing field editor, and even going into the database exp_layout_publish table and removing the field layout json completely but no luck?

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the channel's publish layout using the link below the field list in the sidebar, then reloading the edit screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need to reset the [**Publish Layout**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/publish_page_layouts.html). Select the member groups for which the layout should be reset and click the "Reset Layout" button. Then refresh the browser window. You'll then need to rebuild your Publish Layout.

[image]

Comment: Yes!  that seems to do it, not sure how it got all messed up but that seemed to clean it up, thanks!

Comment: I've been seeing similar issues on EE 2.7.0--and I'm also using Field Editor. So, it's maybe a Field Editor-related issue. But, resetting the layout--or, just saving the layout, does reset things and then all is well.

Comment: You are my HERO!!! I've literally been wreaking my brain all day long!

Comment: You're welcome:) Vote the answer up if it worked for you.